# Groovy: Class fields default conditional values

Tags: groovy, groovy-console, groovy-eclipse

I have below sample classes in my application:

```
class A {
   Integer a
   String b
   Integer c = (a < 5) ? a+5 : a+10
}

class B {
   void method1() {
      A a = new A(a:4, b:"test")
      log.print("c: ", a.c)
   }
}
```

When my code is calling method1, then it outputs c = 14. but ideally it should 9.

How we can solve this without explicitly setting value for c?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: This code, as is, would crash with a `NullPointerException` during initialization of `c` because `a` would be null. Maybe your actual code is different?

Comment: In actual code, only difference is that - the field datatype is Boolean instead of Integer

Comment: i can't understand why it should be `9` when `(4 > 5) ? 4+5 : 4+10` returns 14 for `a=4`

Comment: Typo :P Corrected condition, thanks!

Comment: "In actual code, only difference is that - the field datatype is Boolean instead of Integer" - Is there some reason that you asked for a solution for `Integer` instead of `Boolean`?

Answer (score 1):

Not 100% sure of the question, and the example won't print anything as it will fail to add 5 to null, but an alternative might be to use the @Lazy annotation to defer creation of the value until such time as it is requested, ie:

```
class A {
   Integer a
   String b
   @Lazy Integer c = { (a < 5) ? a+5 : a+10 }()
}
```

After it has been requested, it will keep this value, no matter how you change a and b (unless you change c yourself).  From the question, I have no idea if this is what you want or not

Answer (score 0):

```
class A {
   Integer a
   String b
   def getC(){ (a < 5) ? a+5 : a+10 }
}

class B {
   def method1() {
      A a = new A(a:4, b:"test")
      println("c: " + a.c)
   }
}

new B().method1()
```

Comment: FYI... The requirements in the question are not entirely clear but the attempt made in the code included in the question suggests that `c` should only be assigned a value once.  The way the code in this answer is written, the value of `c` can change over time.  Specifically, it would change if `a` or `b` was ever changed.  That might or might not be the intent.

Comment: i got the requirements this way ))  `without explicitly setting value for c`.

Comment: Right.  I understood the without explicitly setting value for `c` part.  What I am pointing out is that the value of `c` will change when the value of `a` or `b` changes, even without explicitly setting a value for `c`.  That may indeed be the intent, I am not saying it is a mistake.  I am just pointing out that it is inconsistent with 1 way to read the intent that could be read in the original code.